# updating all column values by adding a char with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I have a table with column for storing product code.

```
   | product_id | Product-name | product_code|
   |    1       | soap         | QTI4589     |
        2         abc            DRT45869
        3         xyz            IND458
```

I want to update all values under column product_code with  QTY-4589 , DRT-45869, IND-458 ...

means want to put "-" between code and number.

Tried with `replace()` mysql function but not working. Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the [INSERT(str,pos,len,newstr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) mysql function ???

```
UPDATE table_name SET product_code= INSERT (product_code,4,1,"-") WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with  some mysql functions `CONCAT()` , `LEFT()` , `MID()` , `LENGTH()`

Try below :

```
UPDATE table SET product_code=CONCAT(LEFT(product_code,3),'-',MID(product_code,4,LENGTH(product_code)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the code always three chars? if so you can use

```
UPDATE `table` SET `product_code` = CONCAT( 
    SUBSTRING( product_code, 0, 3 ),
    '-',
    SUBSTRING( product_code FROM 4 )
)
```